# How to set max value of the column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have any problem with homework, could you help me? :)

1. Create table CONTEST that will store data about chess contest for the employees in the company. Columns of the table:

Empno        digits, up to 6 digits (employee numer) 
firstname     text, up to 20 characters
surname       text, up to 30 characters
startdate      date (the date of a game during contest)
department   digits, up to 3 digits
score               digits, the highest possible score is 500.

I have tried following codes:
score number(3) <= 500
score number(3) between 0 and 500

```
create table contest1
(empno number(6),
firstname varchar2(20),
surname varchar2(30),
startdate date,
department number(3),
score number(3) between 0 and 500)
```

Comment: Strange design. I'd have a foreign key to the table employees, where first name and last name should be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a contraint

```
create table contest1
(empno number(6),
firstname varchar2(20),
surname varchar2(30),
startdate date,
department number(3),
score number(3) CONSTRAINT score CHECK (score BETWEEN 0 AND 500))
```

Comment: Thank you! have a good day ;)

Comment: @matklim if this answer solves your problem, then you might considering accepting it as the correct answer. I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, we can use `CHECK` constraint. You can give a constraint name and condition. For your reference, I have given a simple example.

Try this:

```
create table contest1
(empno number(6),
firstname varchar2(20),
surname varchar2(30),
startdate date,
department number(3),
score number(3) CHECK (score between 0 and 500))
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70138)

Cheers!!

EDIT

Demo with insert and errors: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70138/3)

Answer (score 1):

Your size limits are correct. The 500 as maximum value can be resolved via a check constraint, as David Weber explained. You can also create a trigger before insert or update and do the checking there, if you want something more complex, like a log record to be created, for example.